# slider image not working in mailchimp template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is added html:

```
  <div  class="x-flexslider x-flexslider-shortcode x-flexslider-shortcode-3" data-x-element="slider" 
  data-x-params="{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;slide&quot;,&quot;slideTime&quot;:&quot;1500&quot;,&quot;slideSpeed&quot;:&quot;600&quot;,&quot;controlNav&quot;:false,&quot;prevNextNav&quot;:false,&quot;slideshow&quot;:true,&quot;random&quot;:false}" >
  <ul class="x-slides">
  <li  class="x-slide" ><img src="http://li.alertid.com/imp?s=114143&amp;sz=728x90&amp;li=*listid*&amp;e=*femail*&amp;p=*placementID*" border="0" height="90" width="504px"></img></li>
  <li  class="x-slide" ><img src="http://li.alertid.com/imp?s=114143&amp;sz=728x90&amp;li=*listid*&amp;e=*femail*&amp;p=*placementID*" border="0" height="90" width="504px"></img></li>
  <li  class="x-slide" ><img src="http://li.alertid.com/imp?s=114143&amp;sz=728x90&amp;li=*listid*&amp;e=*femail*&amp;p=*placementID*" border="0" height="90" width="504px"></img></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

The class name: class=`"x-flexslider x-flexslider-shortcode x-flexslider-shortcode-3"` added for image slideshow.

This is code added to my mailchimp email template, but it doesn't work,

But it is working in localhost,

the class=`"x-flexslider x-flexslider-shortcode x-flexslider-shortcode-3"` it enable the js when it is running in localhost, but when i upload in mailchimp and run, it doesn't show js script when i check inspector.